# Neural Network: Different number of nodes and hidden layers, but exact same test & train accuracy

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network

I just started studying NN. In the class, the teacher gave us a code to experiment with, in google colab. I tried changing the number of nodes in each hidden layer and the number of hidden layers, and print out test accuracy and train accuracy. I've tried many configurations but the accuracies did not change. Like, it will stay exactly at 0.7857142857142857 (this is the actual number) unless I reshuffle the samples.

The teacher said that accuracy can't be changed that easily. But I don't believe her. I think there is something wrong with the code because there are too many similar digits.

Here are the codes I think are necessary to post.

Model

```
class Model():
    def __init__(self):
        self.layers = []
        self.L = 0
        self.W = {}
        self.b = {}
        self.A = {}
        self.Z = {}
        self.dA = {}
        self.dZ = {}
        self.dW = {}
        self.db = {}
        self.cost = 0.
        self.m = 0
        self.lam = 0
        self.cost_history = []
        self.acc_history = []
        self.alpha_history = []
        self.alpha = 0.
        self.iterations = 0
    
    def add_layers(self, list_of_layers):
        self.layers = list_of_layers
        self.L = len(self.layers) - 1 # Number of layers excluding the input feature layer
    
    def init_params(self):
        for i in range(1, self.L + 1):
            self.W[str(i)] = np.random.randn(self.layers[i], self.layers[i - 1]) * np.sqrt(2. / self.layers[i - 1])
            self.b[str(i)] = np.zeros((self.layers[i], 1))
    
    def forward_prop(self, X):
        self.A['0'] = X
        
        for i in range(1, self.L + 1):
            self.Z[str(i)] = np.dot(self.W[str(i)], self.A[str(i - 1)]) + self.b[str(i)]
            if i == self.L:
                # Output layer, Sigmoid activation
                self.A[str(i)] = sigmoid(self.Z[str(i)])
            else:
                # Hidden layer, Relu activataion
                self.A[str(i)] = relu(self.Z[str(i)])
    
    def compute_cost(self, Y):
        self.cost = -1 * np.sum(np.multiply(Y, np.log(self.A[str(self.L)])) + 
                           np.multiply(1 - Y, np.log(1 - self.A[str(self.L)]))) / self.m 
        
        if self.lam != 0:
            reg = (self.lam / (2 * self.m))
            for i in range(1, self.L + 1):
                reg += np.sum(np.dot(self.W[str(i)], self.W[str(i)].T))
            self.cost += reg
            
        self.cost_history.append(self.cost)
    
    def backward_prop(self, Y):
        # We need dA[str(L)] to start the backward prop computation
        self.dA[str(self.L)] = -1 * (np.divide(Y, self.A[str(self.L)]) - np.divide(1 - Y, 1 - self.A[str(self.L)]))
        self.dZ[str(self.L)] = np.multiply(self.dA[str(self.L)], sigmoid_derivative(self.Z[str(self.L)]))
        self.dW[str(self.L)] = np.dot(self.dZ[str(self.L)], self.A[str(self.L - 1)].T) / self.m + (self.lam/self.m) * self.W[str(self.L)]
        self.db[str(self.L)] = np.sum(self.dZ[str(self.L)], axis = 1, keepdims = True) / self.m
        self.dA[str(self.L - 1)] = np.dot(self.W[str(self.L)].T, self.dZ[str(self.L)])
            
        for i in reversed(range(1, self.L)):

            self.dZ[str(i)] = np.multiply(self.dA[str(i)], relu_derivative(self.Z[str(i)]))
            self.dW[str(i)] = np.dot(self.dZ[str(i)], self.A[str(i - 1)].T) / self.m + (self.lam/self.m) * self.W[str(i)]
            self.db[str(i)] = np.sum(self.dZ[str(i)], axis = 1, keepdims = True) / self.m
            self.dA[str(i - 1)] = np.dot(self.W[str(i)].T, self.dZ[str(i)])
    
    def update_params(self):
        for i in range(1, self.L + 1):
            self.W[str(i)] = self.W[str(i)] - self.alpha * self.dW[str(i)]
            self.b[str(i)] = self.b[str(i)] - self.alpha * self.db[str(i)]
    
    def train(self, X, Y, iterations = 10, 
        alpha = 0.001, decay = True, decay_iter = 5, decay_rate = 0.9, stop_decay_counter = 100,
        verbose = True, lam = 0):
        
        self.m = Y.shape[1]
        self.alpha = alpha
        self.iterations = iterations
        self.lam = lam
        
        # initialize parameters
        self.init_params()

        for i in range(iterations):
            # forward prop
            self.forward_prop(X)
            # compute cost
            self.compute_cost(Y)
            # backward prop
            self.backward_prop(Y)
            # update params
            self.update_params()
            # evaluate
            self.acc_history.append(self.evaluate(X, Y, in_training = True))
            # save alpha
            self.alpha_history.append(self.alpha)
            # learning rate decay
            if decay and stop_decay_counter > 0 and i % decay_iter == 0:
                self.alpha = decay_rate * self.alpha
                stop_decay_counter -= 1
            # display cost per iteration
            if verbose:
                print('Cost after {} iterations: {}'.format(i, self.cost))
    
    def predict(self, X, in_training = False):
        if in_training == False:
            self.forward_prop(X)
            
        preds = self.A[str(self.L)] >= 0.5
        preds = np.squeeze(preds)
        return preds
        
    def evaluate(self, X, Y, in_training = False):
        examples = X.shape[1]
        
        pred = self.predict(X, in_training = in_training)
        pred = pred.reshape(1, examples)
        diff = np.sum(abs(pred - Y))
        acc = (examples - np.sum(diff)) / examples

        return acc
```

Dataset

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv('https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/haberman/haberman.data', sep = ',', header = None)
data.head()

X_train = data.iloc[:,:-1]
Y_train = data.iloc[:, -1]

X_train = np.array(X_train)
Y_train = np.array(Y_train)
Y_train = Y_train.reshape(Y_train.shape[0], 1)

mean = np.mean(X_train, axis = 0)
variance = np.var(X_train, axis = 0)

X_train = np.divide((X_train - mean), variance)

Y_train = Y_train - 1
# Changing label 1 to 0 and label 2 to 1
```

Split & Shuffle data

```
# Split the data into test and train sets
from sklearn.utils import shuffle

X_train, Y_train = shuffle(X_train, Y_train)

X_test = X_train[250:,:]
Y_test = Y_train[250:,:]

X_train_ = X_train[:250,:]
Y_train_ = Y_train[:250,:]

X_train_ = X_train_.reshape(3, 250)
Y_train_ = Y_train_.reshape(1, 250)
X_test  = X_test.reshape(3, 56)
Y_test  = Y_test.reshape(1, 56)
```

Creating a Model

```
m = Model()
m.add_layers([3, 16, 16, 1])

m.train(X_train_, Y_train_, iterations = 5000, alpha = 0.9
         , decay_iter = 10, decay_rate = 0.98, stop_decay_counter = 100
         , verbose = False, lam = 2)
```

Evaluate

```
print('Test set acc = ', m.evaluate(X_test, Y_test))
print('Train set acc = ', m.evaluate(X_train_, Y_train_))
```

What I did in the experiment.

1. Shuffle, train several models (different in number of nodes and hidden layers), and evaluate

```
# Model examples
m.add_layers([3, 16, 16, 1, 50, 3, 25, 7, 99, 1])
m.add_layers([3, 1, 55, 19, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 75, 80, 3, 12, 1])
```

2. Reshuffle, evaluate

Result: Every model has the exact same train and test accuracy unless the data is reshuffled.

The teacher told me that it's just my thought, and it's not true.
Could you please tell me what is wrong to get this result?

Comment: Have you check if the model always converges to a specific case, which might be predicting all the samples as zero, or one (or two based on your labels)? If this is the case, try tweaking your learning rate. You might got stuck at a local minimum.

Comment: I just checked the prediction values, and found that they are always zero. I will try to find a solution. Thank you very much.